# Tracing down routing errors in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am going through my first [RoR tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#top) and came up on an action controller routing error.  I have checked my code at least 8 times, but can't figure out the issue.  I'm sure this will happen again in the future.  My question is, in general, how should I go about solving these errors?  If it's relevant I am using RVM, Rails 3.0.1 and Ruby 1.9.2.

For reference to what I am currently dealing with, here are some of the files:

**pages_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @title = "Home"
  end

  def contact
    @title = "Contact"
  end

  def about
    @title = "About"
  end

  def help
    @title = "Help"
  end
end
```

**layout_links_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

    describe "LayoutLinks" do

      it "should have a Home page at '/'" do
        get '/'
        response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Home")
      end

      it "should have a Contact page at '/contact'" do
        get '/contact'
        response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Contact")
      end

      it "should have an About page at '/about'" do
        get '/about'
        response.should have_selector('title', :content => "About")
      end

      it "should have a Help page at '/help'" do
        get '/help'
        response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Help")
      end
    end
```

**routes.rb**

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
  match '/about',   :to => 'pages#about'
  match '/help',    :to => 'pages#help'

  root :to => 'pages#home'
end
```

**Terminal Output**

```
Started GET "/pages/home" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-10-21 06:51:01 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/pages/home"):


Rendered /Users/zak/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/actionpack-3.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.8ms)
```

**Also ran `rake routes` and got**

```
ZKidds-MacBook-Pro:sample_app zak$ rake routes
(in /Users/zak/rails_projects/sample_app)
contact  /contact(.:format) {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}
  about  /about(.:format)   {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"about"}
   help  /help(.:format)    {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"help"}
   home  /home(.:format)    {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"home"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a route for `/pages/home` defined anywhere. You only have matched root `/` to `PagesController` and its `home` method. So requesting `/` will work, but `/pages/home` not.

You either need to define:

```
match "/pages/home" => "pages#home"
```

or add a resource Pages with additional method `home`:

```
resources :pages do
  get "home", :on => :collection
end
```

Here're some useful routing resources:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/203-routing-in-rails-3

Comment: I made this change in the layout_links_spec.rb file:
require 'spec_helper'

describe "LayoutLinks" do

  it "should have a Home page at '/home'" do
    get '/home'
    response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Home")
  end

And my pages_controller.rb has:
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
 @title = "Home"
  end

Comment: Your test in the comment now matches your `rake routes` output. But both don't match the `routes.rb` **in the question**. Where's your matching for `/home`?

Answer (score 1):

As [@Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986685/tracing-down-routing-errors-in-rails/3986749#3986749) said, you haven't defined a `/pages/home` route, it's only matched to `/`.

The best piece of advise I can give you when dealing with routing problems is to run `rake routes` in the terminal (where you would run `rails server` etc.), which outputs a list of all recognized routes for your app.

Comment: I thought I did route the home page with "root :to => 'pages#home'"

Comment: You routed `/` (root) to the `home` action of `PagesController`. There is no mention of `/pages/home`, so rails doesn't know how to deal with that URL. Bear in mind that multiple URLs can be routed to the same controller/action pair.

Answer (score 1):

if you're following the Ruby on Rails tutorial, it says to delete index.html

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#top